# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)(pt.x * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels()))

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am trying to do the following tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/dfa/tutorial_line_descriptor_main.html

My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

   Mat img_1, img_2;
   img_1 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
   img_2 = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

   if (!img_1.data || !img_2.data) {
       cout << "Error reading image" << endl;
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

// Create binary masks
Mat mask_1 = Mat::ones(img_1.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat mask_2 = Mat::ones(img_2.size(), CV_8UC1);

// Create Binary Descriptor
Ptr<BinaryDescriptor> binary_descriptor = BinaryDescriptor::createBinaryDescriptor();

// Create Line Detector
Ptr<LSDDetector> line_detector = LSDDetector::createLSDDetector();

// Detect Lines
vector<KeyLine> detected_lines_1, detected_lines_2;
Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

line_detector->detect(img_1, detected_lines_1, 2, 2, mask_1);
line_detector->detect(img_2, detected_lines_2, 2, 2, mask_2);
```

When I run the code I receive the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)(pt.x * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\opencv\opencv-master\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 978

I guess it has something to do with the masks.

---

**EDIT:** Even when I exactly copy the code I still get the error but a result as well.

Comment: Perhaps this helps other people: http://answers.opencv.org/question/179930/linesegmentdetector-throws-exception-on-resized-image/?comment=181669#post-id-181669